# performsegue to UINavigationController exception

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, segue

My app functions correctly, but when I enable an "all exception" breakpoint it fails during this segue (***gotoHome***).  If I bypass the navigation controller and go directly to the initial viewcontroller for the navigation controller the segue works fine with the breakpoint enabled.

I am not subclassing or overriding the UINavigationController.  But like I said if I disable the exception breakpoint it works just fine, but I need to be able to enable this to be able to better debug other parts of the application.

Any help would be great.

***viewDidAppear*** from initial StartupViewController.  I have tried with and without the timer with same issue.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { t in

  let u = XXXXXgetUsername()
  let p = XXXXXgetPassword()

  if (u == "" || p == "") {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoLogin", sender: self)
  } else {
    if (getPIN() != "" && !pinVerified) {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoPIN", sender: self)
    } else {
      //FAILS at this segue
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoHome", sender: self) //LINE 37
    }
  }
}
```

}

[image]

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x0000000103ff8f11 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x0000000105702079 CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise] + 9
frame #2: 0x0000000103a17a63 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) 
setValue:forKey:] + 292
frame #3: 0x0000000106745117 UIKit`-[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
frame #4: 0x0000000106f6bea3 UIKit`-[UINibKeyValuePair apply] + 63
frame #5: 0x00000001056a53cd CoreFoundation`-[NSArray 
makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
frame #6: 0x0000000106a355d0 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 
1837
frame #7: 0x0000000106ec5fc2 UIKit`-[UIStoryboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
frame #8: 0x0000000106ed5874 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate 
instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:] + 90
frame #9: 0x0000000106ed5ab8 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 52
frame #10: 0x0000000106750324 UIKit`-[UIViewController 
performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 99
* frame #11: 0x0000000102356516 XXXXXIOS`closure #1 in 
StartupViewController.viewDidAppear(t=0x0000608000167ec0, 
self=0x00007ffd4ed061d0) at StartupViewController.swift:37
frame #12: 0x00000001023565ea XXXXXIOS`partial apply for closure #1 in 
StartupViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) at StartupViewController.swift:0
frame #13: 0x000000010222fcee XXXXXIOS`thunk for @callee_owned (@owned Timer) 
-> () at SensorViewController.swift:0
frame #14: 0x0000000103a60b1e Foundation`__NSFireTimer + 83
frame #15: 0x0000000105692174 
CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
frame #16: 0x0000000105691e32 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
frame #17: 0x00000001056919ea CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
frame #18: 0x0000000105689404 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2308
frame #19: 0x0000000105688889 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
frame #20: 0x000000010d3929c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
frame #21: 0x00000001065a55d6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
frame #22: 0x000000010243a2a7 XXXXXIOS`main at AppDelegate.swift:13
frame #23: 0x00000001093d6d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

[image: AppDelegate]

Comment: It is failing on "self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoHome", sender: self) //LINE 37"

This is all in the stacktrace . I have included all code pertaining to the issue

Comment: could you show me AppDelegate.swift file `frame #22: 0x000000010243a2a7 XXXXXIOS`main at AppDelegate.swift:13`

Comment: Edited OP to show AppDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the view in the storyboard a recreated and linked my view controller to the new view and the exception went away.  Not sure what the error was but this solved it.